# Retrieve the value of countdown in controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

`<timer interval="1000" countdown="120">{{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>`
How can I watch the value of countdown in controller?

Comment: have you tried: $scope.$on('timer-tick', function (event, args) {...}

Comment: No but i tried with `$scope.$watch('countdown', function(event,args){})`

Comment: Yeah it's working thank you @o4ohel